# Need help in changing certain images based off checked boxes in PHP

Tags: php, html, loops

basically my program is to load in images from a directory. Then with each image is a comment box, a check box (checked for the user wants to replace it) and then a button which allows the upload of another picture to replace the old one.

So far here is my code .

```
    <?php


$folder = "images/";
$filetype = '*.*'; // will need to add extensions here


$files = glob($folder.$filetype); // load in files
$count = count($files); // count them


echo '<table>';
$imageCount = 0;

$checkArray = array();
$commentArray = array();
$imageArray = array();

var_dump($_POST);
echo $_POST['check'][0];

for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {


    $fileName = substr($files[$i],strlen($folder),strpos($files[$i], '.')-strlen($folder));

    //replace the file here if needed

    if (isset($_POST['check'][$i])){

    $num = $_POST['check'][$i];

        if (isset())

    }

    echo '<div id = "container">';


        echo '<tr><td>';

        echo '<a name="'.$i.'"><img src="'.$files[$i].'" /></a>';
        echo $fileName;


        echo '<form  action = "index.php" method = "POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data">';
        echo '</br></br>Comments:';
        echo '<input type = "text" name = "comments[]" value = "SUP" id = '.$i.'></input>';
        echo '<input type = "checkbox" name = "check[]" value = '.$i.'>Replace?</input>';
        echo '<input type = "file" name = "fileUpload[]" value = "Upload new image." id = '.$i.'';
        echo '</form>';


        echo '</tr></td>';

    echo '</div>';



}
```

Basically I keep running into a problem. I am able to find which boxes are checked, but then the $_FILES will only store various images which don't have an ID with them. Meaning that I am unable to identify which image goes with which box.

Comment: I would imagine the first order of business would be having a way to ID them, wouldn't you think.

Comment: I think you should keep all of them in one multidimensional array

Comment: Perhaps changing all instances of `$i` to `$files[$i]` from `<a name="` ... to `</form>` would help.